# Suggest please a pattern for searching through database

Tags: database, search, relational-database

imagine this kind of db

```
Authors(id, author) 
Publication(id, authorID, Title, Year....)
```

What is the best way to proceed string search queries f.e. "2001 Smith Theory of Evolution", I mean not in particular case, but in general: searching records not by 1 column?

Comment: Look into full text indexing, on your database.

Comment: Alternatively consider a separate search engine, like Solr, for a free text search. http://lucene.apache.org/solr/

Comment: which database are you using?

Answer (score 0):

For a simple/quick solution:

Consider creating a new (fulltext indexed) `terms` column on your Publication table which will receive every text string of interest to search (e.g. author name, pubdate, title).

Then add a `MATCH`/`AGAINST` clause to your query (or `to_tsquery()` for Postgres).

Postgres doc:  http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/textsearch-tables.html
MySQL doc: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html

---

If you find that you need finer control over search relevance, or stock search features like facets and autocomplete, then consider deploying Solr or Elasticsearch as an external index to your database.